# Do transactions have to be in Stored Procedures in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a bunch of update and insert queries which I call from my C# code that need to be in a transaction. I'd prefer to keep them in C# rather than use Stored Procedures. I use SQLCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() to begin and commit the transaction. It works ok till I try commit the transaction, when I get a message that "The COMMIT TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION". I am closing the connection between calls. Is this the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No they don't.

One can control the transaction in C# directly on the connection itself or use an ambient transaction using the System.Transactions namespace if you want the transaction to span across database connections or even different databases (Distributed Transaction).

If you are closing the connection between calls, use the System.Transactions namespace to control your transactions.  The transaction will then span across connections.

Some basic code to use the System.Transactions namespace:

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
     //Do operation 1 on connection 1 (open close connection)
     //Do operation 2 on connection 2 (open close connection)

     scope.Complete();
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but I would add a couple things.  First, when you use TransactionScope, you're involving MSDTC, and so if it decides to escalate the transaction to a distributed transaction, you need to make sure MSDTC is configured and firewall ports are open for it.  Second, and this is more of a reference to the initial question than your answer, is that when you open/close connections in C#, that typically does not map 1:1 with separate sql connections/spids because the driver will pool connections.

Comment: Very good point about MSDTC.  System.Transactions is very easy to use, until your transaction escalates to MSDTC.  We have two databases, an OLTP and audit.  For the audits, I use RequiresNew to avoid the escalation.  We don't really care if the audit fails (not a banking app) so this avoids the escalation and the hassle of MSDTC configruation.

Comment: Wow, this is better than what I was looking for. Elegant and straightforward. Thanks!